# Export IOS Certificates and Configuration Profiles

Tags: certificates, ios, configuration, keychain

Is there anyway to export a configuration profile from an IOS device that you have root on? So I have a device with an MDM profile with login credentials for a wifi network, VPN, and email authentication certificates. Is there anyway to export these certificates and access the 802.1x wifi password? If I cannot individually export these certificates is there a way to export the whole MDM configuration profile? Any advice would be appreciated. I don't even know where the configuration profiles are stored on IOS.